# Binding Issue in Blazor Server App with Form using Drop-Down List

Tags: blazor

I want to get the value selected from a drop-down list in a form and bind the value in order to create a new "location" object using editContext with the Form.

When I attempt to create a drop-down list using the State List I get an error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'ITInfastructureBlazorApp.Models.State'

```
        <InputSelect TValue="State" ValueExpression="@( () => location.state.id)" @bind-value="location.state.id">
            <option value="">--Select State</option>
            @foreach (var state in stateList)
            {
                <option value="@state.id">@state.name</option>
            }
        </InputSelect>
```

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYl3O.png)

[Code Block on Blazor Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9LfU.png)

I initially thought to try the below, but got errors when building.

```
        <InputSelect @bind-value="location.state.id">
            <option value="">--Select State</option>
            @foreach (var state in stateList)
            {
                <option value="@state.id">@state.name</option>
            }
        </InputSelect>
```

[Input Select Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73cFM.png)

Comment: Bind to the foreign key in the location class. StateId??. Remove the value expression and TValue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up creating a new model for NewLocation that did not include the State class as a property. Replacing public State State with public int StateId.

```
 public class NewLocation
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string? Address2 { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string City { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Range(0, Double.PositiveInfinity, ErrorMessage = "Please select a valid State")]
    public int StateId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
}
```

I created a class for CustomInputSelect:

```
public class CustomInputSelect <TValue>: InputSelect<TValue>
{
    protected override bool TryParseValueFromString(string? value, out TValue result, 
        out string? validationErrorMessage)
    {
        if (typeof(TValue) == typeof(int))
        {
            if (int.TryParse(value, out var resultInt))
            {
                result = (TValue)(object)resultInt;
                validationErrorMessage = null;
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                result = default;
                validationErrorMessage =
                    $"The selected value {value} is not a valid number";
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {            
            return base.TryParseValueFromString(value, out result, out validationErrorMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

Finally I added my CustomInputSelect component to the form:

```
        <CustomInputSelect TValue="Int32" ValueExpression="@(()=> location.StateId)" @bind-value="location.StateId">
            <option value="-1">--Select State-- </option>
        @foreach (var state in stateList)
        {
            <option value="@state.id">@state.name</option>
        }
        </CustomInputSelect>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a custom input select for the numeric values and convert the value to int there, as follows:

```
public class CustomInputSelect<TValue> : InputSelect<TValue>
{
    protected override bool TryParseValueFromString(string? value, out TValue result,
        out string? validationErrorMessage)
    {
        if (typeof(TValue) == typeof(int))
        {
            if (int.TryParse(value, out var resultInt))
            {
                result = (TValue)(object)resultInt;
                validationErrorMessage = null;
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                result = default;
                validationErrorMessage =
                    $"The selected value {value} is not a valid number.";
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return base.TryParseValueFromString(value, out result,
                out validationErrorMessage);
        }

    }
}
```

Now you can use of it in your component as below:

```
<CustomInputSelect @bind-Value="location.state.Id">
 <option value="">--Select State</option>
 @foreach (var item in )
  {
    <option value="@state.id">@state.name</option>
  }
</CustomInputSelect>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one page standalone example using the code you're provided showing how to bind into a data object.

It also demonstrates how to show "-- Select a State --" only when nothing is selected and doesn't allow the user to select that option.

```cs
@page "/"
<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<InputSelect class="form-select" @bind-Value=location.StateId>
    @if (location.StateId == 0)
    {
        <option selected disabled value="0"> -- Select a State -- </option>
    }
    @foreach(var state in this.States)
    {
        <option value="@state.StateId">@state.Name</option>
    }
</InputSelect>

@code {
    private Location location = new();

    public class Location
    {
        public Guid Uid { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
        public string Name { get; set; } = "Not Set";
        public int StateId { get; set; }
    }

    public record State
    {
        public int StateId { get; init; }
        public string Name { get; init; } = "Not Set";
    }

    public IEnumerable<State> States = new List<State>
    {
        new State { Name="UK", StateId = 1 },
        new State { Name="France", StateId = 2 },
        new State { Name="Spain", StateId = 3 },
        new State { Name="Portugal", StateId = 4 },
    };
}
```