# Capture user response from different forms

Tags: c#, blazor

Looking for some guidance so i can push ahead, after 4 days of stuffing around i worked out enough of Blazor to add some tabs and fields, now im trying to workout how to capture the responses ( but i have no idea what data type im getting back), how do i manage this?

So example of my code (showing my best guess)

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Member_Type">Member_Type:</label>
    <input @bind-value=Member_Type_1 />
    <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
        <option>Hero - Leader</option>
        <option>Hero - Warrior</option>
        <option>Hero - Wizard</option>
        <option>Henchmen - Humanoid</option>
        <option>Henchmen - Animal</option>
    </select>
</div>


@code {

    private void int Member_Type_1 = 0;
    
  
}
```

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  CS1519  Invalid token 'int' in class, record, struct, or interface member declaration
```

Judging by that i guess its not coming back as a int, its also not coming back as a String so i dont know what im looking for here :)

The goal here is to capture several results from the user and use those results to edit some Values in a Array (but not until a button press). Having only mastered "hello World" in C# 10 years ago and attempting nothing since some guidance to get these into C# so i can try that side would be very helpful.

Comment: `private void int` -> `private int`

Answer (score 1):

```cs
@page "/"
<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-label">Member Type:</label>
    <select class="form-control" @bind=this.Member_Type_1>
        @if (Member_Type_1 == 0)
        {
            <option selected disabled value="0"> -- Select a Role -- </option>
        }
        <option value="1">Hero - Leader</option>
        <option value="2">Hero - Warrior</option>
        <option value="3">Hero - Wizard</option>
        <option value="4">Henchmen - Humanoid</option>
        <option value="5">Henchmen - Animal</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="alert alert-info mt-3">
    Role: @this.Member_Type_1
</div>


@code {
    private int Member_Type_1 = 0;
}
```

You can also see the same code using the Blazor `InputSelect` and linking into a data model here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/75233814/13065781

[image]